# Accessing native function and class names

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-builder, code-assist

Does anyone know how to access the names of all classes and their functions and variables available in the Action script (String, Array, Math...).

I am building some kind of code editor and i want to implement code assist in it. I am using Flash builder. I mean, after all, when u say:

```
var a:String = String.valueOf(12345);
```

then flash builder has to know what "String" and "valueOf" means, so is there any way to access that information?

Comment: [ActionScript® 3.0 Reference for the Adobe® Flash® Platform](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/index.html).  Otherwise, perhaps through `describeType` introspection of packages within playerglobal.swc

Comment: That sounds like a good idea, i will try it, thanks.

Comment: i tried playing around with  describeType, but when i give it a string, it just gives me this: "<type name="String" base="Object" isDynamic="false" isFinal="true" isStatic="false">
    <extendsClass type="Object"/>
    <constructor>
        <parameter index="1" type="*" optional="true"/>
    </constructor>
    <accessor name="length" access="readonly" type="int" declaredBy="String"/>
</type>"    Am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Adobe provides full documentation for their packages in the [ActionScript 3.0 Reference for the Adobe Flash Platform](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/index.html).

> The ActionScript® 3.0 Reference for the Adobe® Flash® Platform
>   contains the ActionScript language elements, core libraries, and
>   component packages and classes for the tools, runtimes, services and
>   servers in the Flash Platform.

Otherwise, you could [`describeType()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/package.html#describeType%28%29) packages from playerglobal.swc.

> Produces an XML object that describes the ActionScript object named as
>   the parameter of the method. This method implements the programming
>   concept of *reflection* for the ActionScript language.

Value parameter may be an instance or class type.

By instance: `describeType(new MovieClip());`

> If the value parameter is an instance of a type, the returned XML
>   object includes all the instance properties of that type, but does not
>   include any static properties. You can check for this condition when
>   you parse the XML object by examining the value of the `<type>` tag's
>   `isStatic` attribute, which is false when the value parameter is an
>   instance of a type.

By type: `describeType(MovieClip);`

> To obtain the static properties of a type, pass the type itself for
>   the value parameter. The returned XML object includes not only the
>   type's static properties, but also all of its instance properties. The
>   instance properties are nested inside a tag named `<factory>` to
>   distinguish them from the static properties. In this case, the
>   `isStatic` attribute of the `<type>` tag is true.

For example, to obtain all variables and accessors of a type for your content assist / intellisense implementation, you could:

```
/**
 * Returns variables and accessors
 */
public function properties(value:*):XMLList
{
    var xml:XML = describeType(value);
    return (xml..variable + xml..accessor);
}
```

Comment: Since i would like to avoid copy-pasting data from the reference guides, i try describeType, but i tried describeType(new String("sometext")).toString();, and only got this: string = "<type name="String" base="Object" isDynamic="false" isFinal="true" isStatic="false">
    <extendsClass type="Object"/>
    <constructor>
        <parameter index="1" type="*" optional="true"/>
    </constructor>
    <accessor name="length" access="readonly" type="int" declaredBy="String"/>
</type>", what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Answer expanded.  Describe type introspects / reflects by generating an XML structure that you would parse.  So for content assist / intellisense functionality, your editor would need to parse this data for functions, variables, accessors, or other members you want to auto complete.

Comment: But, when i write `'describeType(new String("sometext"));`, i get much less information than i need, i dont get any variables, only 1 accessor (i get lenght), i dont get a factory, i get no methods. There must be something i am doing wrong, but idk what, btw. writing `'describeType(String);` gives me more or less the same

Comment: Nevermind, i just tried it for mx.controls.Alert and it works like a charm, thank you, but i still dont understand why it dosnt work for String...

Comment: describeType() wont accept packages, is there a workaround to it?